# nodejs render multiple pages at once

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I've a `contact` page where one can put their `contact details` and `message`. Once they put their info, it is saved into `mongodb collection`. If there is no error i'd want to empty the contact form and display a pop up message saying thank you. Now if i use

```
    app.post("/contact", function(req, res){
    var name = req.body.name;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var phone = req.body.phone;
    var message = req.body.mess;
    var contact_message = new Contact({name:name,email:email,phn_no:phone,message:message});
    contact_message.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return err;
    }
    else {
        console.log("Contact details saved");
        res.render("contact");
    }
  });
```

The above code just renders back the same `contact page` with no thank you message. If i try to create a new `ejs` page ( *eg: thankyoupage*) and render it that page by sending a message using :

```
res.render("thankyoupage",{message: "thankyou"});
```

it will render only the new thankyou page and leave the contact page unaffected. So i won't have a contact page in this scenario. I'd want something that is a mixture of both where i'd show a pop up showing thank you message with empty fields on contact page at the background.Is there anyway i could do that ? Any suggestions/help/example would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your contact page, you can insert a script that runs when the page first loads.   That script checks to see if a certain Javascript variable is set in the page.  If that variable is set, then the script pops you a thank you message.  If the Javascript variable is not set, that script does nothing.

Then, on the server, when you render the page, you pass the template a property that tells it what to insert for the Javascript variable.  That way your rendering operation can control whether the page will popup a message or not.

You can make this as feature-rich as you want.  For example, you could pass the render, the exact message you want the page to show too and the template could put that message into a Javascript variable that the script in the page would show.

Likewise, the popup can be as rich as you want. It could be an entire div taking up the whole page while the contact portion of the page is temporarily hidden or you could just use an `alert()` or `prompt()` message box over the regular contact page.

Comment: i'm not that sure how could i do that, i'm getting all sorts of error if i try to send something from render to javascript

Comment: @scrpaingnoob - you would have to show your template and what you tried for us to know what you did wrong or how to help you fix it.

Comment: i think i got it by the way you said, thanks for the suggestion